# Modify labels in facet_grid on existing ggplot2 object

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

Suppose we have the following dataset:

```
d = data.frame(
  y = rnorm(100),
  x = rnorm(100),
  f1 = sample(c("A", "B"), size=100, replace=T)
)
```

And I want to plot the data using facets:

```
require(ggplot2)
plot = ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) +
  facet_grid(~f1, labeller = labeller(.cols=label_both))
```

Now let's suppose I want to capitalize all columns. It's trivial to do so with the x/y variables:

```
plot + labs(x="X", y="Y")
```

But how do I go about capitalizing the facet labels?

The obvious solutions are:

1. Just change the name of the variable (e.g., `d$F1 = d$f1`) then rerun the code.
2. Create a custom labeller that capitalizes the variable names

However, I cannot do either of these in my current application. I cannot change the original ggplot object; I can *only* layer (e.g., as I do with the x/y axis labels) or I can modify the ggplot object directly.

So, **is there a way to change the facet labels by either modifying the ggplot object directly or layering it?**

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, I was able to solve my own problem by creating my MWE. And, rather than keep that knowledge to myself, I figured I'd share it with others (or future me if I forget how to do this).

ggplot objects can be easily dissected using `str`

In this case, the ggplot object (`plot`) can be dissected:

`str(plot)`

Which lists many objects, including one called `facet`, which can be further dissected:

`str(plot$facet)`

After some trial and error, I found an object called `plot$facet$params$cols`. Now, using the following code:

`names(plot$facet$params$cols) = "F1"`

I get the desired result.